# Creating metadata style in ArcGIS Desktop from GeoNetwork plugin schema?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, metadata, geonetwork, brazil

ArcGIS 10 does not have a  style metadata that meets my specification.

I have a GeoNetwork plugin schema for metadata generation as the Geospatial Metadata Profile of Brazil.

Is it possible to generate a metadata style in ArcGIS from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [ESRI Metadata Toolkit](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/samples-and-utilities/view/productid/17/metaid/1937)? It is made for designing custom metadata styles. Heavy coding required, though.